# JavaFX client-UI won't show alert triggered by host

Tags: java, javafx, observable

I currently have a small Java project where I have to set up a peer-to-peer connection for a small game.
The game is hosted on one client's server, so I will call this client the "host" from now on.
Both UI controllers are observing the GameState.
Clients and host are connected successfully. Now the host can click the button "start game". When this happened both clients and hosts should see an alert, but this won't happen at the client's side. The host will see the alert but the clients wont.

```
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
  if (o instanceof GameState) {
    this.alert("Event", "Event received"
    "An event was triggered by remote control.");
  }
}
```

I have already checked mutliple times if the client receives the updated GameState and that's happening correctly.
I already tried setting up a new scene without success.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution myself.
For those interested, `javafx.application.Platform` is the way to go.
In my case:

```
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
  if (o instanceof GameState) {
    Platform.runLater( () -> this.alert("Event", "Event received"
    "An event was triggered by remote control."));
  }
}
```